# При логине root пользователя в CentOS 7, с установленным GUI Gnome, отображается только черный экран и курсор

Tags: centos, centos7, gnome

При логине root пользователя в CentOS 7, с установленным GUI Gnome, отображается только черный экран и курсор. Если нажать ctrl+alt+f2, и ввести в консоль startx, то оболочка загружается, проблема только с root пользователем, под другими пользователями все ок. Пробовал удалить папку ~/.config , но это проблему не решило.

Comment: это же не ms/windows. здесь учётная запись администратора используется только для выполнения конкретных администрировных задач. запускать от имени администратора кучу «шлака» в виде gui строго не рекомендуется. для повседневной работы (тем более в gui) надо использовать «рядовую» учётную запись.

Comment: Спасибо! Прочитав ваше сообщение, неожиданно, решил другую проблему, которая возникала из-за использования root-пользователя